# Python2.7 list operation with nop

Tags: python, python-2.7, list

I want to append some data to a list according to `condition`:

```
arr = ['abc', ('def' if condition else NOP)]
```

here, if condition is false, what should I do with `NOP` when I want `arr` to be only contains `abc`?

Answer (score 5):

Just do it in another line:

```
arr = ['abc']
if condition:
    arr.append('def')
```

Comment: Is it possible to add the `if` statement within the list operation?

Comment: Why would you want that? Is there a reason to? There are many ways to do the same thing in python, but only a few that are clear.

Answer (score 3):

```
arr = ['abc'] + (['def'] if condition else [])
```

Answer (score 0):

You might also use a nested conditional generator:

```
>>> ['abc', *(x for x in ['def'] if True), 'ghi']
['abc', 'def', 'ghi']
>>> ['abc', *(x for x in ['def'] if False), 'ghi']
['abc', 'ghi']
```

Not sure whether that's any cleaner, though; maybe if there are more elements.

Comment: On closer inspection, the question is tagged Python 2.7, for which this does not yet work...